# Subsetting data.table with a condition

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

How to sample a subsample of large data.table (`data.table` package)? Is there more elegant way to perform the following

```
DT<- data.table(cbind(site = rep(letters[1:2], 1000), value = runif(2000)))
DT[site=="a"][sample(1:nrow(DT[site=="a"]), 100)]
```

Guess there is a simple solution, but can't choose the right wording to search for.

**UPDATE:**
More generally, how can I access a row number in data.table's `i` argument without creating temporary column for row number?

Comment: It's unnecessary to `cbind` in your `data.table(.)` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the biggest benefits of using `data.table` is that you can set a key for your data.
Using the `key` and then `.I` (a built in vairable. see `?data.table` for more info) you can use:

```
setkey(DT, site)
DT[DT["a", sample(.I, 100)]]
```

As for your second question `"how can I access a row number in data.table's i argument"`

```
# Just use the number directly:
DT[17]
```

Comment: thanks! just for clarification, how can I sample every even number using i argument?

Comment: +1. With what you're doing you'll have to subset from the inner `DT[..]`, that is: `DT[DT["a", sample(.I, 100)]$V1]`. Alternatively, you can use the `which` argument in `[.data.table` as follows: `DT[sample(DT["a", which=TRUE])]`

Answer (score 4):

Using `which`, you can find the row-numbers. Instead of sampling from `1:nrow(...)` you can simply sample from all rows with the desired property. In your example, you can use the following:

```
DT[sample(which(site=="a"), 100)]
```